# How do I get the height of the bottom tabBar in react-native-navigation

Tags: react-native-navigation

I'm using WIX navigator in my react native app, and I'm animating a component based on whether or not the keyboard is showing. My problem is that the *bottom* and *endCoordinates* change depending on if the *drawUnderTabBar* style setting is true or false.

Obviously, I can get/set the value of *drawUnderTabBar*, but how do I get the height of the tabBar when it's showing?

Answer (score 1):

Looking in the [source code](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/blob/1d9b02d4a1dc02713d5e9d70e9e16e13737df7d2/android/app/src/main/java/com/reactnativenavigation/views/utils/Constants.java#L6) is a good way to start.

Comment: THANK YOU! I searched for every combination of constants I could think of. Except that one... :)

Comment: This is working for android ;)